# Mockito NullPointerException when object of Repository is created

Tags: android, mockito

```java
public class DriveInteractor implements DriveContract.Interactor {

    private final DriveRepository driveRepository;

    public DriveInteractor(Context context) {
        DriveApplication application = (DriveApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        this.driveRepository = application.getDriveRepository();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Drive> getDrive() {

        List<Drive> drives = driveRepository.getDrives();

        return drives;
    }
}
```

Following is the code for my Test Class for which I am using **Mockito**:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class DriveInteractorTest {

    @Mock
    private Context context;
    @Mock
    private  DriveRepository driveRepository;
    @Mock
    private List<Drive> driveList;

    @Mock
    private DriveApplication driveApplication;

    private DriveInteractor driveInteractor;

    @Before
    public void setUpDriveInterator(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    driveInteractor = new DriveInteractor(context);
}
.....}
```

I have also written a test method in my Test Class. As soon as I run my test method I keep getting a **Null Pointer Exception** pointing towards `DriveRepository`.

I even tried creating an object of my Drive POJO class in `setUpDriveInterator` method and adding to the arraylist, but it doesn't work:

```java
public class DriveRepository {

    private List<Drive> drives;

    public DriveRepository(Context context) {
        drives = new ArrayList<>();
        drives.add(Drive.create(context, "ABC", "Honda"));
.....
       }
....}
```

Which context needs to be passed in DriveInterator for testing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: one cannot just add the `@Mock` annotation to `Context` and expect it to have the target context assigned already... ever considered it being `null` ?? without a stack-trace of the NPE this is most likely the case.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I tried debugging my app and the context is not null.

Comment: can you stub context.getApplicationContext(); something like below Mockito.when(context.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(driveApplication); and try once.

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala Thanks for your commnet. It was the right ans. Please post your comment as the ans so i can upvote and mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stub your context.getApplicationContext(); piece of code in your test method.

something like below `Mockito.when(context.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(driveApplication);`

Hope it is useful.